# Moving Customized WinEdt Dictionary to New Machine

Tags: winedt

I am a user of WinEdt and I am about to get a new computer.  I have a lot of words added to the spell check dictionary (mainly mathematician's names!).  Is there a way to move this list to the new machine.  I am hoping there is a single file I need to move.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of WINEdt?

Comment: On  `winedt.org`, you can find an `InstallDict.edt` macro which makes installation of dictionaries simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to try and answer my own question.  I remembered that Windows has an App Data area.  That lead me to look at

```
C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team
```

which lead me to

```
C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\Dict
```

which had a file named `user.dic`.  I copied it and renamed it `user.txt` and opened it (successfully) in Notepad.  It is indeed my user dictionary!!

Comment: Great! It worked! It was my same concern. too and I got the same intuition, since none of the .dic files into the program original folder included any of the new word I added to my custom dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I had asked WinEdt tech support and they sent a reply explaining how to find where the local data is found

*Yes, your User dictionary is stored in your “Local folder” within the Dict subfolder. All your customizations, if you made changes to defaults, are there in their proper location in the Local Folder. Your can find the location and examine these by going to Options-> Configuration Wizard and pressing the button on the lower right hand side, “Browse Local Folder (%b)”

Copy it over to the new installation*